# httpwebrequest with "infinite scrolling" pages?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Some websites (ex Facebook) only load a certain amount of the page until you scroll down near the end, then they load more data. Is there a way, using HTTPWebRequest, that you can retrieve all (or more) of the data, than would normally show without scrolling to the bottom?

If I do something like:

```
HttpWebRequest r =  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.facebook.com");
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)r.GetResponse();
```

the response will only show the limited data that would appear if you visited the site and didn't scroll down at all.

Hope this makes sense, I probably could have worded it better.

How can I get more data from the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRequest doesn't help you here. Such sites depend on user interaction (like scrolling) to decide to get more data.

You could use the `WebBrowser` control and actually interact with the web site. That's about the only way, unless there's an API to explicitly get the data.

---

Consider that you want to use HttpWebRequest. This class will send a request to a web server and get the response.

The question you need to ask is, "what request gets sent to the web server to make the page use infinite scrolling"? The answer is, "there *is* no request that is sent to force infinite scrolling". It is the fact that you've scrolled to the bottom that makes the next page appear.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a feeling that may be the case.